# C module DLL for Lua using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, lua

Im trying to create a C DLL to extend my Lua script which I am using in a C++ application.

My DLL code is in "mylib.h":

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lua.hpp"
extern "C"
{
static int l_hello(lua_State *L) {
    std::cout << "sup lol?" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib[] = {
    { "l_hello", l_hello },
    { NULL,NULL }
};

__declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_mylib(lua_State *L)
{
    std::cout << "loading my lib" << std::endl;
    luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
    return 1;
}
}
```

I build the code mentioned above and put the DLL "mylib.dll" in the application debug folder. When I run the app the program crashes on

```
local mylib = require "mylib"
```

with the error "error loading module 'mylib' from file 'C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1Tests\Debug\mylib.dll':
        The specified module cant be found (translated from another language)."

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This usially means that there no needed deps for your dll. Checkout your lib e.g. with dependency walker

Comment: PS. also to use cpp functions you better compile Lua also as CPP. Think about what happens when one of your function e.g. throw exception.

Comment: Does your DLL need to be C++? C++ dlls are a very particular kind of beast. If possible I recommed you to stick to C on DLLs unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: I dont have to use C++ as a DLL but I dont know how to make a C DLL or make a C DLL that can be detected. Whatever I do I run into the same error described above.