# Unable to load simple DLL module with Lua 5.4: "The specified module could not be found"

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll, lua

I'm trying to create a DLL module to be required by a Lua 5.4 script (64-bit Windows). I've created a simple DLL in Visual Studio based on the few examples I was able to find, however when I try to require it, I get the message "error loading module 'testlib' from file 'C:\lua\testlib.dll': The specified module could not be found." This happens when running `require('testlib')` from the command line, as well as from within an embedded script.

I started with C++ because that's what Visual Studio had a template for, but if C is more suitable I'll happily switch. This is very much new territory for me.

---

This is my code. For initial testing purposes it's just exposing a single function that adds two numbers, but the goal is to receive a string and have the OS's text-to-speech read it out. I'm building with Visual Studio, and the dependency is being resolved by vcpkg.

This is my first time working with c++, so please let me know if there's any more important information I should include.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include <lua.hpp>

extern "C" {
    static int add(lua_State* L) {
        lua_Number n1 = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
        lua_Number n2 = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);
        lua_pushnumber(L, n1 + n2);
        return 1;
    }

    static const luaL_Reg mylib[] = {
        {"add", add},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    __declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_testlib(lua_State* L) {
        luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
        return 1;
    }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I've reviewed every existing post I was able to find mentioning this error message, but without luck (almost every example is building for linux, but in my case building for Windows is a requirement).

---

edit 1: [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008253/c-module-dll-for-lua-using-visual-studio) probably counts as a duplicate, but is unanswered and predates Lua 5.4. The comment "C++ dlls are a very particular kind of beast. If possible I recommed you to stick to C on DLLs unless you really know what you are doing." indicates I might be better off making this in C. I did try adapting the code, but the result was the same. Despite someone jumping to conclusions and removing the C tag, it is very much relevant, so I've readded it.

---

edit 2: This is my attempt at the equivalent C code, based on [this example from 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660774/7520417). As mentioned in the first edit, I compiled the DLL but received the exact same error message (except with the new file name of course) when running `require('testc')`.

```c
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

static int add(lua_State* L) {
    lua_Number n1 = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    lua_Number n2 = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);
    lua_pushnumber(L, n1 + n2);
    return 1;
}

static luaL_Reg const mylib[] = {
    {"add", add},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

__declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_testc(lua_State* L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
    return 1;
}
```

---

edit 3: I was going to accept the answer, but found it had been deleted by a moderator. I'm hesitant to repost the solution, because I'm not sure why it was originally removed. This error appears in a number of places on Stack Overflow, but none of them mention this solution so I'll try to summarize:

The reason the DLL failed to be loaded was because the lua.dll dependency was missing. **The solution was to copy the lua.dll along with my new module.**

While this seems counterintuitive, the reasoning is that the host Lua runtime does not make the libraries available to the modules it loads.

So in this case "the specified module" in the error text refers to the dependency, not the module being loaded.

A comment said this could likely be simplified by statically linking the dependency such that it's compiled/bundled with the module in the same DLL. I haven't confirmed this yet, but it's not necessary to resolve the initial problem, so I still consider this issue solved.

Comment: If you ask about C++, why do you spam tag C watchers?

Comment: I think "specified module could not be found" means Lua found your file, but `LoadLibraryEx` failed (and gave this message) which might mean a missing dependency. Only dependency is probably Lua itself (assuming that's dynamically linked from your DLL). I think if your host Lua is statically linked, your lib won't be able to use it, so you could dynamically link (probably preferable?), or also statically link from the lib (and really make sure both are using the same exact version). If your host is dynamically linked, it should already be loaded, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Or I guess, technically the host can statically link and the lib can dynamically link, but the system will have to be able to load a DLL copy of Lua when loading any lib (which could be shared between multiple libs), but this is still multiple copies of Lua like everything statically linking.

Comment: "why do you spam tag C watchers" because Lua-compatible DLLs can be made with either, and people who have made one with C before are just as likely to have have the answer. This is a question first and foremost about building a DLL that can be used within Lua, using C++ is not important, it's just what Visual Studio has project templates for.

Comment: `#include <lua.hpp>` - this is not C. `extern "C"` is also invalid C.

Comment: @273K at least read the whole question